# Can the Apple T2 chip be used as a TPM to enable BitLocker?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, encryption, t2

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro, with the [Apple T2 Security Chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862). I have installed Windows 10 via Boot Camp, and that is working well. I would like to turn on BitLocker in W10 and take advantage of that encryption, but when I try to enable BitLocker, Windows returns the error *This device can't use a Trusted Platform Module.* Is there any known way to use the T2 chip as a TPM for the purpose of enabling BitLocker?

(I do realize one can [enable BitLocker without a TPM](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/) - I am not trying to solve that problem. This is about using the T2 chip.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the T2 cannot in any way be used as a TPM for BitLocker. TPM for BitLocker is not a generic term for any type of trusted platform module, but rather it needs to be specifically the Intel TPM specification (latest version is 2.0). The T2 chip does not work in a way compatible with the TPM specification.

Comment: I just came across [this article](https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/for-security-how-bad-are-tpms-and-how-good-is-the-apple-t2-chip-a561bda34e6) which is a good comparison of the two - he at least sounds like he knows what he's talking about. 